# npm install --production --prefix giving an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

I went to an issue while trying to create some build steps for Node project.

Issue: 
`npm install --production --prefix ./.build` - Gives me an error
[image]

I tried changing the name in the package.json but I still receive the same error:

[image]

Comment: You mean to say the folder name? See the second image I changed the 
"name": "----------node-api-test" in package.j. Still am getting the same error

Comment: Not clear. I am trying to do npm install to .buid folder in the project. Even I tried changing the name in package.js still getting the same error

Comment: Its `package.json` not `js`. You are not supposed to install anything inside the `build` folder, it's contents are be to created automatically whenever you compile your source code to create a production build (using webpack, babel or whatever). Please read `npm` docs first to understand how node and npm works, instead of making assumptions on what you should do

Comment: I am not installing any thing new, I need to move node_module to my .build folder. Thank you

Comment: You don't need to move `node_modules` inside the build folder. All the required code from packages inside `node_modules` is already in your build bundle. Why do you need the `node_modules` inside the `build` folder?

Comment: The issue with aws sam. Sam needs code folder we mention in CodeURI should have the node_module folder also. So I used babel to build the code and put in .build folder with out any folder structure and now the issue is how to move the node_module with build steps

Comment: I have never used AWS SAM but in situations like this, usually you upload your whole source code to server and build process happens on server. Look through AWS docs they usually have tutorial on how to deploy your application for all major framework on all their server types.

Answer (score 0):

The current working drectory is important to `npm`.
Are you sure you're in your app folder?
Please type `pwd` command if you're unsure...
That error is usually produced when running `npm` command from a wrong folder...

Comment: I don't have an app directory itself. All I have is  src folder

Comment: The main issue is the application is aws lamda application and aws sam requires node_module should be available with the source code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you have the project you are working on at the moment as dependency in your project - check the `package.json` file. Try changing the name of the project in `package.json`.

Comment: See the second image I changed the 
"name": "----------node-api-test" in package.j. Still am getting the same error

Comment: Do you have any special dependencies? Including another directory instead of a node module?

Comment: I don't have any other dependency. All I need is to move the libraries to .build folder with my build code. So my deployment will be smooth and error free